# Can't boot Windows Vista after installing Ubuntu

Tags: 12.10, boot, dual-boot, windows, windows-vista

I'm very new to Ubuntu, and have come to this point that I can't boot back to my Windows Vista anymore.

I thought that I would get some kind of dual boot in the beginning when booting my computer, but this doesn't seem too happen and I don't have the slightest idea on how to fix this. I was looking for help here at askubuntu, but I couldn't seem to find anything. I'm too new with this software.

I'll need hints and tips on how to fix this

Thanks for your time folks!

Comment: how did you installed ubuntu? `installed along side windows`? are you seeing grub menu to select windows 7?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 2):

When booting back up, you should see the GRUB menu. In this menu, you should see a list of the operating systems you can boot up. Arrow down to Windows Vista and hit enter. Then it should boot Windows Vista.  If you don't see the GRUB menu or you don't see Windows Vista listed, then you probably accidentally erased Vista while installing Ubuntu.

Comment: @AlexandrosChristophoros If you can actually confirm you accidentally erased Vista, then you should create a new question - probably on http://superuser.com -- asking for help on recovering your files.

Comment: @Johnny I may have come to this point where I may have deleted my Windows Vista when I did the partition stuff when I installed Ubuntu is there a way to get it back?

Answer (score 0):

You will find al the necessary here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Does this also include recovery on files? Because I may have overwrited my Windows Vista

Answer (score 0):

If you have overwritten your Windows , then I'm very sorry to say it cannot be fully recovered.

However , you may be able to recover your deleted (important) documents and files using the software named **File Scavenger**.

Hope this helps.